# Prority Queue LL Implementation in C faulty? Keeps linking back to the other instructions

Tags: c, linked-list, queue, priority-queue

When I try to use the Priority Queue class I implemented as a Linked List, I find out that my pointers keep on pointing to each other. I modified it from this Simple Queue implementation I found online: http://ben-bai.blogspot.com/2012/04/simple-queue-data-structure-in-ansi-c.html

This is my Queue and Node Structs:

```
typedef struct Node
{
  Instruction pointer;
  struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct Queue
{
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;

  void (*push) (struct Queue *, Instruction);
    Instruction (*pop) (struct Queue *);
    Instruction (*peek) (struct Queue *);
    Instruction (*removeNode) (struct Queue *, Instruction);
  int size;
} Queue;
```

Instruction is a pointer to another struct I have implemented called Command.
This is my push and pop methods:

```
void
push (Queue * queue, Instruction instr)
{

  Node *n = (Node *) malloc (sizeof (Node));
  n->pointer = instr;
  n->next = NULL;

  if (queue->head == NULL
      || n->pointer->priority > queue->head->pointer->priority)
    {
      n->next = queue->head;
      queue->head = n;
      queue->size++;
    }
  else
    {
      Node *temp = queue->head;
      Node *p = temp->next;
      while (p != NULL)
        {
          if (p->pointer->priority < n->pointer->priority)
            {

              n->next = p;
              temp->next = n;
              queue->size++;
              return;
            }
          p = p->next;
          temp = temp->next;
        }

      n->next = NULL;
      temp->next = n;
      queue->size++;
    }
}

Instruction
pop (Queue * queue)
{

  Node *head = queue->head;
  Instruction node = head->pointer;

  queue->head = head->next;
  queue->size--;

  free (head);
  return node;
}
```

This is the while loop I use to traverse the LL to just print the values of the nodes and the instructions they point to:

```
Node *n = ready.head;
while (n != NULL)
  {
    puts ("right here now");
    printNode (n->pointer);
    n = n->next;
  }
```

This will print out
Instruction 2
Instruction 3
Instruction 2
Instruction 3
Instruction 3
And so forth on and on, endlessly.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: The example you copied is a simple queue and not a priority queue. Assuming you copied it faithfully and it works unamended, the problem is probably within your priority queue code (i.e. your amendment to `push`). I suggest you produce a simple unit test for it and see if that fails. If it does, post the entire unit test here as compilable source. For instance, you will need a simple definition of the `Instruction` `typedef struct`, such that it holds at least a priority.

Comment: Okay I'll do that thank you

Comment: I unit tested it, and realized it was my other pieces of code that was seg faulting. THANK YOU for your help